# Getting coordinates of pellets in a browser-game (data from UDP) - wireshark

Tags: encryption, udp, wireshark

I have been experimenting a bit with wireshark and have read that I should be able to see game data being sent back and forth. I thought that since my connection with the game server is unencrypted and that game packets are sent using the UDP (user datagram protocol) I should be able to see the information the server is sending me. I got some rather interesting results below.

[image: udp]

My ultimate goal is to get the coordinates of the pellets (the small circles) and later names on the "*Leaderboard*" (that is perhaps easier since names on there seem to change less frequently) in `agar.io` which is a browser-based game.

---

I have noticed that the packets are of different lengths (I suppose that is what "Len=" stands for) 101, 117, 133, 149, 165, 181, 197, 229, 439, 469, 565, 1445.

The server is sending mostly sending packages of Len=117(most of these) and 101.

---

So the question is: **where do I find the information(coordinates of pellets or/and names on the leaderboard) that I am looking for?**

Comment: But what is your question?  The numbers highlighted in your image (which are the UDP headers, not the data) do not match the numbers in your question btw.

Comment: Wireshark question belong on superuser. In this case you have neglected to ask any question at all.

Comment: @grochmal I am sorry that I didn't make that clear enough. I updated the post.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I am really sorry, should this thread be moved to superuser somehow then?

Comment: What is "Leaderboard"? what protocol it uses on top of UDP? Whatever is in the body of that UDP packet it has no magic number (0x306a8a4a is no magic number for any stream type as far as I know and can search for).  Trying to brute force a pattern from UDP would require thousands of packets, there certainly is a better way of doing it than looking at the UDP payloads (e.g. tinkering with the client itself in a debugger).

Comment: The leaderboard is the area where users with the top-scores are, located in the top right when you play the game I mentioned above. I found this page about protocol `http://agar.gcommer.com/index.php?title=Protocol`. I couldn't make out any useful information from it unfortunately.

Comment: That page argues that the first thing in a message is an opcode.  The first thing you have in your packet is a 0x30, but there is no opcode 48.  That probably means that there is something more, e.g. another layer of encapsulation.

Comment: Did you have success with your project? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a github project that attempts to document the Agar.io Protocol via reverse-engineering which you might want to take a look at.  The meaning of the data depends on the version of the protocol in use, apparently.

For more details, see: https://github.com/forairan/Agar.io-Protocol/blob/master/Protocol.md.

If you want Wireshark to dissect the protocol for you, you can write a custom dissector for it.  To more quickly accomplish this, you might want to consider a Lua-based dissector, which doesn't require that you recompile Wireshark, but if you want to contribute the dissector to be included with Wireshark, then you should consider writing it in C.  The Wireshark site has a lot of helpful information in this regard, but perhaps a look at the [Wireshark developer's guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/) would be a good place to start.  The [Wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/) also contains a lot of helpful information, particularly for Lua (sample scripts are available, for example), should you decide to attempt to write a Lua-based dissector.